# Search index with python without a loop

Tags: python, list, indexing, binary-search

I have a list in python, for example A = [-22,-10,0,3,8] and I want to find A[x]=x, that means that the index and number in the list have the same value. In this case x=3 because A[3]=3.

Can I find x without a loop?

EDIT: It's a academic problem and I have a clue "You don't need to visit each position in the array" and the numbers will be ordered and unique

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use a loop?

Comment: Yes, you could use recursion. That will be less efficient and clumsier than using a loop, so I assume you're asking out of academic curiosity.

Comment: Yes, It's a academic problem and I have a clue "You don't need to visit each position in the array"

Comment: but A[1] =1, A[2] = 2, A[3] = 3, you need to loop somehow.

Comment: using a loop does not mean you have to visit *each* position... you could stop after the first match.

Comment: Hi, when I wrote the example I didn't think.. I had fixed the array and there is a only solution.. And yes, you could stop the loop..

Comment: Any option you use is going to use a loop of some sort in the background. What's the point of avoiding a loop?

Comment: what you are looking for is a fixed point. and if there is no rule as to how your list was build (a function? random?) there is probably no way to be more efficient than to just loop... if the entries in the list are some kind of function values there may be better ways.

Comment: Both examples you gave (pre and post-edit) were monotonically increasing lists... was that just by coincidence or is that part of the problem statement?

Comment: @cwbusacker: not true. A recursive function will (1) not need a loop and (2) not (necessarily) "visit each position".

Comment: You are right, but recursion is no better than a loop. Yes you could loop until you find the first one, but it depends on what this is for.

Comment: @YunaA. It's not coincidence you will have the number ordered and unique

Answer (score 3):

Given that the list elements are integers, in order and distinct, the problem can be solved by [binary search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). This is because the sequence `a[i] - i` is non-decreasing. A binary search does not visit "each" position in the array; only O(log n) of them.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a list comprehension (but that is really just hiding the loop):

this will give you all indexes where A[i] == i:

```
indexes = [i for i,a in enumerate(A) if i==a]  # [1, 2, 3]
```

if you only want the first one you can use the next function:

```
index = next((i for i,a in enumerate(A) if i==a),None) # 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets Python to do the looping for you:

```
list(map(lambda x: x[0], filter(lambda x: x[0] == x[1], enumerate([-2,1,2,3,8]))))
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for lulz, the recursive function:

```
def find(l, i):
  if i>=len(l):
    return None
  elif l[i]==i:
    return i
  else:
    return find(l, i+1)

# for searching in the whole list the second argument needs to be 0
print(find([-22,-10,0,3,8], 0))
```